# Get oAuth token for Dwolla's Reflector/test account (Dwolla API)?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, dwolla

Can you get an oAuth token for Dwolla's "Reflector"/test account?

It's not clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- the Reflector's account sole purpose is to reflect any money sent to it. Giving out an OAuth token for that account will compromise the security of the funds it temporarily holds.

Comment: it would be nice if there was a test account for oAuth purposes too